# Please what is wrong with this code? I get invalid syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, create-table

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE customers
(
    id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name            TEXT NOT NULL,
    billing_address TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE products 
(
    id    INTEGER PRIIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    price NUMBER NOOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE orders 
(
    id               INTEGER NOT NULL,
    customer_id      NUMBER NOT NULL,
    product_id       NUMBER NOT NULL,
    delivery_address TEXT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customers(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES products(id)
);
```

Comment: You have used `noot` instead of `not` in `products` table ddl

Comment: For future reference, always post the complete content of any error message you encounter - ALL of it.

Comment: Priimary Key?( extra i..) Looks like a bit of syntax highlighting/ spell-check would go a long way...

Answer (score 1):

If you are running SQL Server, there are the following problems with your code:

- There is `NUMBER` datatype in SQL Server: you can use `DECIMAL`, or a floating-type datatype such as `FLOAT`.
- The datatype of a foreign key column must match that of the parent column.
- `TEXT` is a legacy datatype, that is planned for removal in a future version of SQL Server; you can use `NVARCHAR` instead.
- There are also a few typos in your code.

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id                 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name               NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    billing_address    NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE products (
    id                 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    price              DECIMAL(15,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
    id                 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    customer_id        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    product_id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    delivery_address   NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customers(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(product_id)  REFERENCES products(id)
);
```

---

If you are running SQLite (which you also tagged), then you just have to fix the typo on `NOOT NULL`. I would also recommend aligning the datatype of the foreign key columns, although SQLite would still allow mapping a `NUMBER` to an `INTEGER`.